# Rails 3.2/Active Admin - Custom asset pipeline path not working, resulting in ActionView::Template::Error (file.js isn't precompiled)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

In my Rails 3.2 app I am using Active Admin for an administrative dashboard. I created a custom javascript file to use on one of my forms and added it to `/initializers/active_admin.rb` like so:

```
config.register_javascript 'my_file.js'
```

Since Active Admin looks for this file in `/assets/active_admin`, but that folder is not directly available by default, I created it and put `my_file.js` there.

I noticed that, when deploying my app to Staging, I couldn't view `/admins` and got this error in the console: `ActionView::Template::Error (my_file.js isn't precompiled)`. So I did some looking around on SO, found this question, and implemented the poster's fix in `application.rb` like so:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/active_admin"
  end
end
```

After deploying to Staging again, I'm still getting the same error. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should pass path to file, instead of directory, like

```
config.assets.precompile += ['my_file.js']
```